# I don´t know how to move a gauge in a layout by using the margins

Tags: android

I have gauge in app, and I want to move it to central of page. But if I do anything, no change will occur

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_noise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sc">


    <com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.TubeSpeedometer
        android:id="@+id/gauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="600dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Odmeraj amotsferu"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can see it in app:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: dude you have to set 'TubeSpeedometer' constrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use constraints as suggested by **`@Harin Kaklotar`**.

Change

```
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.TubeSpeedometer
    android:id="@+id/gauge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="600dp"
    />
```

to

```
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.TubeSpeedometer
    android:id="@+id/gauge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="600dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

You've already used these constraints in `tv_noise`. So I suggest you to first read up on [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) and [How to Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_noise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sc">


    <com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.TubeSpeedometer
        android:id="@+id/gauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Odmeraj amotsferu"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! your solution and solution by second user is work.